# What else does UIView.exclusiveTouch do?

Tags: iphone, uiview

exclusiveTouch property:

Setting this property to **YES** causes the receiver to block the delivery of touch events to other views in the same window. The default value of this property is **NO**.

And in a similar discussion:
  [Why doesn't UIView.exclusiveTouch work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843338/why-doesnt-uiview-exclusivetouch-work)

> If a finger contacts an exclusive-touch view, then that touch is delivered only if that view is ***the only view tracking a finger*** in that window.

I tried this:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

aView = [[AView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; // full screen
bView = [[BView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240)]; // top half

// Both A and B are tracing the touch event. (touchesBegan & touchesMove)
aView.exclusiveTouch = NO;
bView.exclusiveTouch = NO;

[window addSubview:aView];
[window addSubview:bView];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

No matter what value the exclusiveTouch is,
a) aView always traces the touchesMove event (finger from bottom to top-half)
b) **only** bView traces the touchBegan event.

It seems like the quote from another post is false?
If so, doesn't it imply exclusiveTouch property is useless at all?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This result might be caused by subView mask, but I'm still confused what this property is for?