# Allow only one UIView to be touched

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, events, uiview

I have three `UIViews`:

[image: views]

`B1` and `B2` are subviews of `A`.

`B1` and `B2` may have one or more subviews.

I want that only one **view can be touched at the same time.**

For example:

The user touches `B1` (or one of its subviews) with the first finger, and then, without releasing it, touches `B2` (or one of its subviews) with the second finger. Now, `B1` should receive all events in its bounds, but not `B2`. Same thing the other way around.

Is this possible to accomplish **without subclassing any of these views**?

If not, what's the easiest/cleanest way to do it?

**Edit:**

About `exclusiveTouch` and `multipleTouchEnabled`:

These properties are not valid for my problem.

`multipleTouchEnabled`: Only determines whether or not multi-touch-events are delivered **in the same view**. So disabling multi-touch on view A (which is the default anyways) will not block view B1 and B2 from receiving touch events at the same time.

`exclusiveTouch`: Doesn't work either. As far as I have understood, `exclusiveTouch` only works **inside the frame of the view**. So setting `exclusiveTouch` on view B1 and B2 has no effect.
See these two stackoverflows for reference:

[Why is UIView exclusiveTouch property not blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946147/why-is-uiview-exclusivetouch-property-not-blocking)

[Why doesn't UIView.exclusiveTouch work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843338/why-doesnt-uiview-exclusivetouch-work)

Comment: Disable multitouch on the views :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is **not possible without subclassing**. If anyone can prove me wrong, I'd be happy to see their solution. Anyways, this is how I solved it:

First, I subclass view `A`, I call the subclass `ParentView`. ParentView needs pointers to `B1` and `B2`. I also add an additional pointer that is later used to store the currently selected view. Then, I override `hitTest`:

```
@interface ParentView : UIView
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* viewB1;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* viewB2;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* currentlyTouchedView;
@end

@implementation ParentView

- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (self.currentlyTouchedView == nil) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.viewB1.frame, point)) {
            self.currentlyTouchedView = viewB1;
        }else if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.viewB2.frame, point)) {
            self.currentlyTouchedView = viewB2;
        }
    }else {
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(self.currentlyTouchedView.frame, point)) {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

So, what this code does is, it stores the view that is first touched. If one is already stored, it returns nil on `hitTest`, which eats up any additional touch events.

Now, where does `currentlyTouchedView` get set back to nil? For that, I subclass `UIWindow` and override `sendEvent` to check if all touches have ended:

```
@implementation EventOverrideWindow

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];
    BOOL allTouchesEnded = YES;
    for (UITouch* touch in event.allTouches) {
        if (touch.phase != UITouchPhaseCancelled && touch.phase != UITouchPhaseEnded) {
            allTouchesEnded = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allTouchesEnded) {
        ParentView* parentView = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).parentView;

        parentView.currentlyTouchedView = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

I know this is not a very elegant solution and I'd appreciate if someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting both `exclusiveTouch` and `multipleTouchEnabled` to `YES` for B1 and B2.

**Edit**: I'm assuming from the wording “B1 should receive all events in its bounds” that you want to receive the touches directly in B1 & B2, not their subviews. If you want to restrict the touches to the B1/B2 bounds but handle them in the subviews I think you need to subclass B1 and B2, or A.

**Edit 2**: If it's the subviews of B1 and B2 that are interactive, you would need to set these properties to `YES` on all interactive subviews (recursively). But this also makes all subviews mutually exclusive to touch, not just between B1 and B2.

Comment: See my edit about `exclusiveTouch` and `multipleTouchEnabled`. About your edit: I want the touches to be handled normally. So say there is a tableView as a subview of view B1, I want to be able to interact with it normally. But when I first touch B2, I don't want the user to be able to interact with the tableView in B1.

Comment: @megamer `exclusiveTouch` means that the view gets touches exclusively for the _window_, so these settings would work if B1 and B2 were the views you wanted to receive the touches exclusively. However, since it appears that you want their subviews to receive the touches, it won't work. You could set these properties to `YES` in each subview of B1 and B2 (recursively if they have further subviews), but this would also make touching multiple subviews mutually exclusive.

Comment: edit2: Yes, that would be an option, but it's not what I want - everytime I add a new subview, I'd have to think about this. I'd like to find a solution that is permanent/valid for any subview inside of views B1 and B2.

Answer (score 0):

When B1 or B2 is touched, set `exclusiveTouch` to `YES` for that view and then set it back to `NO` again when the touches end. This means only the exclusive view will receive touches.

If you want to get touches outside the exclusive view's bounds you can store a reference to the view somewhere when you make it exclusive (`myExclusiveView`), then override `hitTest:withEvent:` for view A (or any superview) and have it return `[myExclusiveView hitTest:withEvent:]`.